# convert mysql (on duplicate key ) query to oracle merge

Tags: mysql, oracle, oracle11g

```
INSERT INTO table1(id,dept_id,name,description,creation_time,modified_time) 
VALUES('id','dept_id','name','description','creation_time','modified_time') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE dept_id=VALUES(dept_id),name=VALUES(name),
   description=VALUES(description),creation_time=VALUES(creation_time),
   modified_time=VALUES(modified_time)
```

I used the below oracle to convert the above mysql query. The query fails. Can you please help me figure out what is wrong with the oracle query.

```
Merge into table1 t1 using 
    (VALUES ('id','dept_id','name','description','creation_time','modified_time')) as temp 
    (id,dept_id,name,description,creation_time,modified_time) on t1. id = temp.id 
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET dept_id=t1.dept_id, description=t1.description, name=t1.name, 
    creation_time=t1.creation_time, modified_time=t1.modified_time 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (id,dept_id,name,description,creation_time,modified_time) 
VALUES ('id','dept_id','name','description','creation_time','modified_time')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, you need to use a table or subquery in the `using` clause (in your case, you need a subquery).

In Oracle, you can use the dual table if you need to select something without needing to select from an actual table; this is a table that contains only a single row and a single column.

Your merge statement should therefore look something like:

```
MERGE INTO table1 tgt
USING (SELECT 'id' id,
          'dept_id' dept_id,
          'name' NAME,
          'description' description,
          'creation_time' creation_time,
          'modified_time' modified_time
     FROM   dual) src
ON tgt.id = src.id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET  tgt.dept_id       = src.dept_id,
       tgt.description   = src.description,
       tgt.name          = src.name,
       tgt.creation_time = src.creation_time,
       tgt.modified_time = src.modified_time
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT
    (tgt.id,
     tgt.dept_id,
     tgt.name,
     tgt.description,
     tgt.creation_time,
     tgt.modified_time)
  VALUES
    (src.id,
     src.dept_id,
     src.name,
     src.description,
     src.creation_time,
     src.modified_time);
```

Note how the `when not matched` clause uses the columns from the source subquery, rather than using the literal values you supplied. (I assume that in your actual code, these literal values are actually variables; `creation_time` is a pretty odd value to store in a column labelled creation_time!).

I've also switched the aliases to make it clearer where you're merging to and from; I find this makes it easier to understand what the merge statement is doing. YMMV.